# "position:fixed;bottom:0;" doesn't work in iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, css, mobile

It seems that the iPhone doesn't support the css property `"position:fixed"` is there a good work around for this?  I have looked at various JavaScript/jQuery solutions that slide the element vertically but that is not the best solution, I would like the element to be fixed to the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look into: http://jquerymobile.com for a complete solution.

But here is a library independent (its just a script) to make this work:
http://cubiq.org/iscroll

Comment: Thanks for your comment i have tried iscroll but it isn't very good to be honest.

Comment: None are very good in general. Even Gmail's was so bad that they ended up removing it and using that floating panel instead. Sucks, but true. Id also try: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/scrollview/

Comment: so i tested out the iscroll solution and i would say it was the closest thing i could get to a position fixed on an iphone.

Comment: If this is the solution you went with mark it as correct so others searching can see what you went with easily :) good luck with your iPhone site! I was honestly pretty disappointed too about this as I wanted to make pure HTML5 apps with an iPhone look

Comment: @Oscar Godson, i went with some custom jQuery code in the end, but this was the easiest to implement and use out the lot.  by chance do you know anything about media queries ?

Comment: CSS media queries? Sure! If you elaborate on StackOverflow I can try to answer it for ya, or you can DM/tweet me on twitter @oscargodson

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="a"> 
  //your website content
</div>
<div id="b">
  //your fixed footer
</div>
```

- set the height of b to whatever you need (css)
- set the height of a to screen.height - b.height (js)
- also set a style to overflow:scroll;

The downside of this solution is that you won't use the main window scrollbar, but I think there are none on an iphone, so...

Comment: Overflow scrolling on the iPhone requires using two fingers to scroll. It's a horrible UI for the main content of your page.

Comment: Major +1 for Kevin Ballard's comment. This is nightmare UI for the user - most users don't even know that the two finger scroll even exists.

Comment: God, please no two finger scrolling. I honestly didnt know you could do that until earlier this year

Comment: sorry im looking for a more robust solution